# Forming Conditional Probabilities in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, autoencoders

This is a repost from stack, but I think it may be more applicable here. Granted there is even a bounty for it there, if someone could answer it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421179/forming-conditional-distributions-in-tensorflow-probability

I am using Tensorflow Probability to build a VAE which includes image pixels as well as some other variables. The output of the VAE:

```
tfp.distributions.Independent(tfp.distributions.Bernoulli(logits), 2, name="decoder-dist")
```

If we treat this output as essentially a joint distribution (ignoring the VAE details), I am trying to understand how to form other conditional distributions based on this which I can use with the inference methods (MCMC or VI) in tfp. Say the output above was P(A,B,C), how would I take that Independent distribution to form a posterior P(A|B=b,C=c) that I could perform a hamiltonian MCMC on?